# Slow gem install on centos vm

Tags: ruby, rubygems

At work I have a private gems server on a centos 7 with ruby 2.2.
We updated our ruby version to ruby 2.4 and now new gems we want to use can't be installed on this server.
So we created a new server using ruby 2.4 on centos 7.

The problem is that installing gems is taking stpendesly amount of time. Something we didn't have problem with on the old gems server.

How can I fix it?

Note the servers are offline so we use gem install  - - local

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Here we help programmers.  What is your programming question?

Comment: The programming question is how can they speed up gem install. Seems clear enough.

Comment: I would consider using RVM to help manage this. https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle install --jobs=4` to support parallel downloads, though it's not a huge increase (reported as [1.6x here](https://philna.sh/blog/2017/06/12/speed-up-bundle-install-with-this-one-trick/).

Gem install can indeed be slow, hopefully running it once will help with local caching on CDNs.